# How to run parallel triggered pipeline in Azure DevOps that will consume related artifact from triggering build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am having problems to run an ADO pipeline with DownloadPipelineArtifact that downloads artifact right from the build that triggered it.
The idea is to have a pipeline A that creates artifact(s) and a pipeline B that consumes those.
However, the pipeline A can be run multiple times (let's call those builds A1, A2, A3) and produce different artifacts (let's call them a1, a2, a3). Then, when those pipelines succeed, the pipeline B runs after each completion (let's call them builds B1, B2, B3).

Now, we need those pipeline to consume the artifacts related to them, so B1 consumes a1, B2 consumes a2 and B3 consumes a3. The ADO task DownloadPipelineArtifact@v2 has an option "specificBuildWithTriggering" that should result in such behaviour. But I cannot get it to work - all runs consume the latest artifact (a3)!

The outcome presented in pseudo graphical form:

```
A1 --> a1 --> B1 is triggered --> downloads and uses a3 (should be a1)
A2 --> a2 --> B2 is triggered --> downloads and uses a3 (should be a2)
A3 --> a3 --> B3 is triggered --> downloads and uses a3 (should be a3)
```

The code I use is as follows (anonymized a little bit):

We have a pipeline in ADO that creates a simple artifact:

```
# pipeline A
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: runName
    displayName: Tag name (run name)
    type: string
    default: test-tag

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: Info
    jobs:
      - job: info
        displayName: Display info
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo "This is triggering another pipeline"
              echo "Putting ${{ parameters.runName }} into $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/runName"
              echo ${{ parameters.runName }} > $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/runName
            displayName: 'Create runName file for publish'

          - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/runName
            artifact: runName
```

This pipeline is then created in ADO and has an ID of XXXX.
It produces an artifact which preserves a runName parameter value (As default it is save to folder and filename just as artifact name, with contents of a parameter value inside).
This pipeline when finished, is supposed to trigger another ADO pipeline which is supposed to read from artifact and echo the parameter (for now, of course).
This is done by creating a pipeline like this:

```
# pipeline B
trigger: none # do not start automatically unless specific trigger is defined below

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: another-helper-repo
      type: git
      name: ourproject/repo1
      ref: refs/tags/sometag
    - repository: tenant
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/main
      name: ourproject/repo2

  pipelines:
    - pipeline: a-trigger
      source: ourproject/A # the triggering pipeline name
      project: ourproject
      trigger: true

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'specific'
              project: 'ourproject'
              definition: 'XXXX'   # triggering pipeline ID
              specificBuildWithTriggering: true  # use the build ID that has triggered you
              artifactName: '' # all artifacts
              targetPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
          - bash: |
              echo "Working..."
              echo "System.ArtifactsDirectory: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) - listing :"
              ls -al $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
              echo "runName value:"
              cat $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/runName/runName
            name: Information
```

This pipeline indeed triggers after a while when the pipeline A is run successfully.
However, problem is that when we run pipeline A couple times, each with different parameter runName, the pipeline B does NOT get that parameter - instead it gets the latest one. So if we quickly run pipeline A three times, each time with parameter test1, test2, test3 - the result is that we have three times pipeline B showing only test3.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: May I know if below solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Tested the scenario and can reproduce the issue. It seems to be an issue on the [DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines) with `specificBuildWithTriggering: true` option enabled.

As a workaround we can [download an artifact from a specific build run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines#download-an-artifact-from-a-specific-build-run). We can use the predefined variable `$(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID)` as the specific pipeline id. Thus, it will identify the pipeline id and download the artifact from the triggering build. See [Pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables) for details.

So, the pipeline B should look like this:

```
# pipeline B
trigger: none # do not start automatically unless specific trigger is defined below

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: another-helper-repo
      type: git
      name: ourproject/repo1
      ref: refs/tags/sometag
    - repository: tenant
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/main
      name: ourproject/repo2

  pipelines:
    - pipeline: a-trigger
      source: ourproject/A # the triggering pipeline name
      project: ourproject
      trigger: true

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'specific'
              project: 'ourproject'
              definition: 'XXXX'   # triggering pipeline definition ID
              buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
              pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.a-trigger.runID)' #Triggering pipeline id
              artifactName: '' # all artifacts
              targetPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
          - bash: |
              echo "Working..."
              echo "System.ArtifactsDirectory: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) - listing :"
              ls -al $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
              echo "runName value:"
              cat $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/runName/runName
            name: Information
```